# Not able to cherry pick

Tags: git

I have a branch(say xyz) on which lot of commits have happened after I have deployed that branch on live. There is a particular commit which I want to pull on the live server which is an urgent bug-fix.

I tried to cherry-pix that commit in the live server, but it says that it cannot find the particular commit.
I thought that as the commit is on the same branch so the cherry-pick may not be happening. So create a new branch from the xyz branch and tried to do the cherry pick. Again that did not work.

Is it because I created the branch after the commit happened in the branch?

Regards,
Pankaj

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting? How are you specifying the commit? By SHA1? Is it possible that you have multiple local repos and the commit you're trying to cherry-pick is not available in the one you're using?

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by "the commit is on the same branch". A branch of the same name in a different repository? Surely you're not trying to cherry-pick something that's an ancestor of your current commit...

Answer (score 3):

You can only cherry-pick commits locally available, so if your bug-fix has not been pushed it's best to pull the live branch, cherry-pick locally and then push.