# GitHub client prevents cherry-pick: "you are not able to cherry-pick from and to the same branch"

Tags: github-for-windows

Using the GitHub client for Windows I am trying to cherry pick a commit from my `development` branch into `main` branch so that I can do a quick deploy of a small change instead of merging everything that is currently on `development` into `main`, as those changes are not yet ready to be deployed.

To do this, I branched off of `main` and called the branch `fix/some-fix`. In the GitHub client, I switched to the `fix/some-fix` branch, and looked at the commit history to find the specific commit that I made to `development`.

However, the button to perform the cherry pick is greyed out and hovering over it says,

`You are not able to cherry-pick from and to the same branch`

The commit I am trying to cherry-pick is definitely not on the same branch. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In part, this appears to be a UX issue with the GitHub client. That warning message could be more clear. The important point to keep in mind is this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5232603/4015994)):

> *"You can only cherry-pick commits locally available"*

What I was doing wrong was attempting to cherry-pick a commit that was not locally available because I was not on the branch that contained the commit. Specifically, I was on `fix/some-fix` and trying to cherry-pick a commit from `development`, when I should have been on `develop` and cherry-picking the commit to `fix/some-fix`. In other words, I had the directionality confused.